# Haskell: write file with Unicode charactes in name

Tags: haskell, unicode

I need to write a file with Unicode characters in name:

```
module Main where

main :: IO ()
main = do
  writeFile "йцу" "qwe"
```

It crashes with run-time error: `openFile: invalid argument (invalid character)`

How do I write file with Unicode characters in name?

Comment: Does your file system supports filenames in cyrillic?

Comment: Yes, of course. So goes for my locale.

Comment: That *is* how you write to a file whose name contains Unicode characters. Something else is wrong.

Comment: This works just fine on MacOS. What are you running this on?

Comment: Thanks for feedback. The problem actually is in running program from stack, not in haskell or anything else. Just needed to execute binary directly.

Comment: @ValentinShirokov That is still worrisome. What exactly did you do to trigger that behavior from `stack`?

Comment: Do you have your source file encoded in UTF-8?

Comment: How exactly are you running from Stack ? Also did you try to use plain Cabal and was the problem not reproducible there ?

Comment: `$ stack new test simple; cd test; echo '  writeFile "йцу" "qwe"' >> src/Main.hs; stack --nix build; stack --nix exec test`. Plain `cabal run` works just fine. Please note that there are two spaces before `writeFile`, stackoverflow just ate one of them.

Comment: @arrowd Yes, file is in UTF-8.

Comment: Are you using nix os ?

Comment: @Sibi yes, I am. I currently don't have currently any "pure" Linux machine at hand to test. This reproduces on any of my NixOS machines. I tested on stack versions 1.5.1 and 1.3.2.